# Stocktwits - number of followers for symbol

Tags: stocktwits

Been looking at the API docs and was wondering if anyone figured out a way to retrieve the number of followers that are following a specific symbol. It looks like this is possible on a per-user basis (find what symbols they're following) but wasn't sure if there was something like that for symbols.

Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the follower counts are not available in the open API. They are available to our partners that license the extended data. Sorry about that. If you are integrating into a paid product for your customers, we would love to talk and make not only followers data but sentiment and more available. Please contact us.

Comment: Is this still the case? I have a client who really only would like the follower count. It is a perk, and not a deal breaker, so he can do without. Current price would be nice, but its also available at other places.